# datetime error in generated columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table 'tbl1' in which there are two fields:

1. created_at of type datetime and NULL is allowed.
2. num_days of type INT(11) and NULL is allowed and default value is 3.

I am trying to create a generated column 'cut_off' of type **date** and column of STORED type.

I am using this command:

```
alter table tbl1 add column cut_off date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATE(created_at + num_days)) STORED;
```

I am getting this error:

> ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '20181119063562'

But in this query:

```
select distinct(DATE(created_at + num_days)) from tbl1;
```

is running fine and giving no errors.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are adding seconds not days, and a minute cannot have 62 seconds

perhaps try

```
DATE(created_at + INTERVAL num_days DAY)
```

Comment: Why this query 'select distinct(DATE(created_at + num_days)) from tbl1;' is working then ?

Comment: it probably works for certain values but for others produces NULL as an error, and MYSQL is objecting to the error in the ALTER query